# Convert list to a node pointer

Tags: search, linked-list

I am trying to write a function to search a linked list for an element, but when I try compiling it I get an error saying `cannot convert list to node* in assignment`. Why is that happening? Isn't my list a node* already?

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

struct node {
    int data;
    node * next;
};

class list {
    public:
        list();
    void createnode(int value);
    int size();
    void insert_position(int pos, int value);
    void delete_first();
    void delete_last();
    void remove(int pos);
    int get(int pos);
    int search(int searchNum);
    node * head, * tail;
};

list::list() {
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

node * search(list l, int value) {
    node * p;
    for (p = l; p != nullptr; p = p - > next) {
        if (p - > data == value) return p;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No your list is not a node*. list is just a class.
What you are doing is assigning a class object to node*.

```
node * search(node* l, int value) {
    node * p;
    for (p = l; p != NULL; p = p -> next) {
        if (p -> data == value) return p;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```